# Validate incoming data from third party: accept only what is strictly needed or tolerate more?

Tags: validation, language-agnostic

I have to deal with some data input from a third party. It is actually a mapping from strings to strings, and in order to do my work I need some keys to be defined, and their values must be of the expected type.

The question is: should I accept other keys that I do not need and do not disturb the normal functioning of my programme?

For instance, let's say this is strictly what I need (for the sake of the argument, let's assume an incoming json):

```
{"a": "hello",
 "b": "world"}
```

But, should I accept this as valid input?

```
{"a": "hello", 
 "b": "world", 
 "c": "patata"}
```

- If I am strict, the service I am offering may not be so userfriendly, in the sense that maybe I prevent some users from reusing some of their existing code, and they must adapt it just for me (I see this as a weak argument).
- On the other hand, not being strict on what I accept, may lead to confusion when some of my coworkers try to debug some possible future problems (I do not see this as a very strong argument either).

Comment: The real question is: Do both formats contain valid data? In other words: Are you just interested in any JSON containing the keys "a" and "b", or are you parsing a JSON in a specified format, that might contain other keys in which you're simply not interested, or are you parsing a JSON in a specified format, that must consist of only the keys you're interested in?

Comment: Well, as I explained, I strictly need only ``a`` and ``b`` defined. If there is some other stuff defined (e.g.: ``"c:" "patata"``), it is just ignored by my programme. So both forms are acceptable for my code. The question is exactly that: should I swallow and ignore? or just reject if it is not 100% what I need?

Comment: Let me put it this way: Are you happy with any JSON containing the key "Id" (implicating quite possibly a large portion of JSON's found in the wild) and consider it valid data? If so, ignore other keys. If not, be strict and reject. Putting it more succinctly: If you can deal with any JSON having your required keys, regardless if they contain keys not meaningful to you, then ignore other keys. Otherwise be strict.

Comment: I can perfectly deal with data input with irrelevant keys to me. It is not a problem... the question was rather "is this a good practice"? swallowing vs rejecting and its possible future consequences (unnecessary huge data, possible confusion for other developers, etc). Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

being strict is, imo, way better. it's much clearer documentation for end-user. reusing existing code is not a problem - it requires only adding simple filter.
same with your team. it's much easier to maintain module/functionality that has very restricted input. because it's easier to understand all possible flows.

but some frameworks by default offers the second option and much more code needs to be added to get second option. when you add static typing to it then it's still good enough documentation for other programmers. so in practice you can often encounter the second approach